# Python / Git / Module structure best practice

Tags: python, git

We have a lot small projects that share common utility "projects"

**Example**:
utility project **math** contains function **add**
project **A** and project **B** both need **math.add**
project **A** has nothing to do with project **B**

so is it a good idea to have 3 git repositories (project_A,project_B and math) and clone them locally as

```
/SOMWHERE/workspace/project_A
/SOMWHERE/workspace/math
```

and have in /SOMWHERE/workspace/project_A/__init__.py something like

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../math')
import math

math.add()
```

I have read [Structuring Your Project](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) but that doesn't handle SCM and sharing modules.

So to sum up my question: is

```
sys.path.append('../math')    
import math
```

good practice or is there a more "pythonic" way of doing that?

Comment: Install "math" locally using distutils or similar, so A and B can use it.  (Since `math` is common infrastructure used by unrelated projects, it's likely to be relatively stable.)

Comment: You do know about git submodules?

Comment: @iveqy: yes I know about them and maybe that's the way to go. But after reading articles like [Sharing code and why git submodules is a bad idea.](http://uttamkini.com/2012/12/01/sharing-code-and-why-git-submodules-is-a-bad-idea/) I decided not to use them

Comment: @SvenMarnach: thanks, didn't know about distutils so I had to read them up. Maybe I didn't make that clear in my question: math is going to be changed quite regularly (i.e. commits are made by people working on A and B) so distributing and installing it doesn't seem to be very practiable

Comment: Submodules require some git knowledge, however that article is just fud.number 1 and 3 are false and number 2 isnt strange at all ifyou understand git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules are a suboptimal way of sharing modules like you said in your comments. A better way would be to use the tools offered by your language of choice, i.e Python.

First, [create virtualenvs](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to isolate every project python environment. [Use pip](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to install packages and store dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file.

Then, you can [create a specific package for each of your utils library using distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html) and [share it on Pypi](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial).

If you don't want to release your packages into the wild, you can also [host your own Pypi server](http://justcramer.com/2011/04/04/setting-up-your-own-pypi-server/).

Using this setup, you will be able to use different versions of your libraries and work on them without breaking compatibility with older code bases. You will also avoid using submodules, that are difficult to use with git.

Comment: but you said you didn't want to build releases all the time because it was changing rapidly.  sigh...

Answer (score 1):

all of what you describe (3 projects) sounds fine *except* that you shouldn't mess around with `sys.path`.  instead, set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

also, if you were not aware of distutils i am guessing you may be new to python development, and may not know about virtualenv.  you should use that too (it allows you to develope against a "clean" python version that has no packages, or only the packages you install for that env).